# Formato diferente para visualização e retorno (bootstrap-datepicker)

Tags: javascript, html5

Possuo o seguinte calendário:

```
Início do período:
<input type="text" id="calendarioIni" name="dataInicio">

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var dataIni = document.querySelector("#calendarioIni");
    var dataFim = document.querySelector("#calendarioFim");

    function checaVazio(){
        var botao = $("#consultar");
        var display = dataIni.val() && dataFim.val() ? "inline" : "none";
        $(botao).css("display",display);
  }

    $('#calendarioIni').datepicker({
        startDate: '01/01/1998', 
        endDate: '31/12/1998', 
        onSelect: checaVazio
    });

    $('#calendarioFim').datepicker({
        startDate: '01/01/1998',
        endDate: '31/12/1998', 
        onSelect: checaVazio
    });


});
```

Gostaria que para o usuário aparecesse no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` mas que retornasse no formato `yyyy/mm/dd` ou até mesmo `yyyy-mm-dd`, como poderia realizar esse procedimento?

Comment: Veja se dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy" te ajuda

Comment: mas o retorno fica desta mesma forma @Zorkind

Comment: No onSelect: function(selectedDate) {} você consegue formata o retorno.

Comment: @Zorkind vc poderia exemplificar para mim? ou então me mandar algum link com isto explicado? sou novo no ramo

Comment: Acho que entendi o que você quer, quando o formulário for postado você quer que o valor vá no formato yyyy-mm-dd certo? dá para pegar o evento de submit e editar o valor do input antes de enviar, entendeu?

Comment: é exatamente isso @Zorkind , porém não sei fazer isso que vc falou

Comment: é o bootstrap-datepicker? ou qual é o plugin?

Comment: @Zorkind , da uma olhada aqui        <?php if(isset($_POST['dataInicio']) && isset($_POST['dataFim']))
                                    {
                                        $dataIni = $_POST['dataInicio'];
                                        $dataFim = $_POST['dataFim'];
                                        $cod_orgao = $_POST['Distrito'];
                                        $cod_unidade = $_POST['Concelho'];
                                    } 
?> 

vc quis dizer antes de enviar eu realizar as trocas?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic boostrap mesmo

Comment: no javascript, isso.

Comment: @V.Avancini você quer essa resposta via servidor? ou no JAVASCRIPT? aonde você quer utilizar a formatação final?

Comment: "Retornasse" vc quer dizer, enviar pro servidor?

Comment: é o seguinte, essa data é utilizada em um select SQL, recebo via Post do html e armazeno em uma variavel no php, e faço a query via php passando a variavel preenchida, entendeu?

Comment: Mas te avisando aqui, deu certo o que vc fez, mas necessito do checaVazio pro usuário não enviar sem as datas e efetuar uma consulta errada

Comment: Minha resposta te dá exatamente o que você quer, no submit do form, mas dá para você fazer isso no PHP também.

Comment: Tudo bem. O que não ficou claro pra mim, é: o cara seleciona a data, blz, aparece no campo no formato dd/mm/yyyy... aí vc quer enviar esse valor pro servidor no formato yyyy/mm/dd numa variável qualquer que vc usa?

Comment: @ÐvÐ utilizo a data em um Select SQL e a data no SGBD está no formato yyyy/mm/dd, ai para fazer isso eu guardo o valor da data em uma variavel php e utilizo ela na query que faço, pegou?

Comment: Consegui entender não. Então será que o problema não seria de php em vez de JS? Desculpe, é que a sua pergunta não está clara. Vc postou um código JS e no final diz "_Gostaria que para o usuário aparecesse no formato dd/mm/yyyy mas que retornasse no formato yyyy/mm/dd ou até mesmo yyyy-mm-dd, como poderia realizar esse procedimento?_".... Seria melhor reformular a pergunta explicando exatamente o que deseja, de onde vem as informações, pra onde vai, como quer etc... Já li umas 20 vezes e não consegui entender rs

Comment: é o seguinte, tenho o campo data, que estou utilizando o bootstrap-datepicker para aparecer o calendario, para o usuario selecionar a data, quando ele clica em um data o campo é preenchido, e gostaria que no campo o formato fosse dd/mm/yyyy (padrão brasileiro de data), porém com essa data eu faço uma consulta SQL, onde meu SGBD trata a data com o padrão yyyy/mm/dd, então gostaria de guardar em uma variável nesse formato para poder realizar meu Select, agora foi?

Comment: Agora melhorou. Vou postar uma resposta e veja se é isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode converter a data de cada campo para o formato `yyyy-mm-dd` direto no PHP quando receber via `$_POST` usando `strtotime()`.

```
$dataIni = $_POST['dataInicio'];
$dataIni = str_replace('/','-',$dataIni);
$dataIni = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dataIni));

$dataFim = $_POST['dataFim'];
$dataFim = str_replace('/','-',$dataFim);
$dataFim = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dataFim));
```

Note que antes da conversão é preciso converter as barras `/` em hífen `-` porque o `strtotime()` não trabalha corretamente com `/`. (**[Veja documentação](https://devdocs.io/php/function.strtotime)**)

Comment: para testar eu fiz da seguinte forma:
 <?php if(isset($_POST['dataInicio']) && isset($_POST['dataFim']))
{
    $dataIni = $_POST['dataInicio'];
    $dataFim = $_POST['dataFim'];
    $cod_orgao = $_POST['Distrito'];
    $cod_unidade = $_POST['Concelho'];
    echo $dataIni."<br>";//Teste para verificar o valor nas variáveis
    echo $dataFim."<br>";
    echo $cod_orgao."<br>";
    echo $cod_unidade."<br>";
} 
?>           
e a data saio no dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @V.Avancini Em vez de enviar a data que está no input, vc tem que enviar a que está na variável que foi criada

Comment: @V.Avancini Pra facilitar, não seria melhor criar 2 inputs escondidos, 1 pra cada data, aí vc envia esses inputs para o PHP

Comment: @V.Avancini Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: o negócio é que a hora importa, no BD tá tudo registrado como 00:00:00, ai dependendo da hora que a pessoa fizer a consulta vai dar errado... o meu Where é a seguinte: WHERE finempe.data_empenho between convert(datetime, $dataIni) and convert(datetime, $dataFim) and finempe.codigo_orgao = 01 and finempe.codigo_unidade = 01

Comment: @V.Avancini Você quer a data + a hora atual?

Comment: não, eu quero que independente da hora que o usuário fizer a consulta retorne tudo 0

Comment: @V.Avancini Então, no PHP vc inclui a hora, por ex.: `$dataIni = $_POST['dataInicio_h'].' 00:00:00';`

Comment: aí @dvd , não deu certo e pior, agora não preenche a variavel data, testei dando um echo dentro do if, olha aí: <?php if(isset($_POST['dataInicio_h']) && isset($_POST['dataFim_h']))
{
        $dataIni = $_POST['dataInicio_h'];
        $dataFim = $_POST['dataFim_h'];
        $cod_orgao = $_POST['Distrito'];
        $cod_unidade = $_POST['Concelho'];
        echo $dataIncio_h;
        echo $dataIni."<br>";//Teste para verificar o valor nas variáveis
        echo $dataFim."<br>";
        echo $cod_orgao."<br>";
        echo $cod_unidade."<br>";
 } 
?>

Comment: @V.Avancini Os campos hidden vc deve colocar junto aos campos do datepicker. Não tem como isso dar errado. Eles são enviados no POST normalmente.

Comment: tá assim: Início do período:
<input type="text" id="calendarioIni" name="dataInicio">
 Fim do período:
 <input type="text" id="calendarioFim" name="dataFim">                                    
  <input type="hidden" id="calendarioIni_h" name="dataInicio_h">
  <input type="hidden" id="calendarioFim_h" name="dataFim_h">

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70445/discussion-between-dvd-and-v-avancini).

Answer (score 0):

Só usar a propriedade format

```js
$('input').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" value="02/10/2017">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto no seu formulário

```
$("#formulario").submit( function() {
    var dateObject = $("#calendarioIni").datepicker("getDate");
    $("#calendarioIni").val(dateObject.getFullYear() + '-' + dateObject.getMonth() + '-' + dateObject.getDate());
});
```

Coloque o id do formulário ali no seletor.

No **PHP** é possível fazer desta forma:

```
$originalDate = $_POST['dataInicio'];
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate));
```

O `originalDate` você coloca o campo de data que você recebe do formulário.

Comment: Pode explicar o motivo do negativo por favor?

Comment: não foi eu que negativei, amigo

Comment: Sem problemas, só quero atender sua necessidade e por enquanto nenhuma das outras respostas fazem o que você quer.

Comment: a que fazia o que eu queria o cara apagou... não entendi o pq... utilizo a data em um Select SQL e a data no SGBD está no formato yyyy/mm/dd, ai para fazer isso eu guardo o valor da data em uma variavel php e utilizo ela na query que faço

Comment: Sim eu entendi, esse código vai alterar o valor do seu input antes de enviar o valor para o servidor. Mas eu acho que dá pra você converter direto no SQL ou até mesmo no PHP não precisa ser no javascript.

Comment: entendi, mas é uma desvantagem fazer no JS?

Comment: Não necessariamente, mas o mais seguro é fazer no PHP.

Comment: entendi, mas como faria isso no PHP, tratando como string mesmo?

Comment: Coloquei ai na resposta

Comment: poderia utilizar a mesma variavel pra fazer isso?

Comment: Editei, algo desse jeito.

Comment: PHP não é muito meu forte kkkkk

Comment: eu pensei em algo como: $dataIni = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dataIni)); funcionaria?

Comment: Acho que sim, mas pelo que to vendo na documentação do PHP esse strtotime é mais para formato em inglês, veja se funciona direitinho e tal.

Comment: eu testei aqui e deu certinho, amigo!

Comment: Que bom, fico feliz :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser configurado a sua maneira e chamar o evento `changeDate` para resgatar o valor escolhido e formatar a nova saída, pode ser utilizado uma função um outro componente de tela ai fica a escolha, exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendarioIni').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: '01/01/1998',
    endDate: '31/12/1998',
    language: 'pt-BR'
  }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    $("#cid").val(e.date.toISOString().substring(0, 10));
    console.log($("#cid").val());
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="calendarioIni" class="form-control" name="dataInicioCalendar">
<input type="hidden" id="cid" class="form-control" name="dataInicio">
```

No seu caso em especifico o que eu fiz, crie um outro campo `input type hidden` e o valor escolhido no primeiro `input` vai formatado para esse `input`, que pode ser resgatado pelo `PHP` e utilizado na sua consulta, exemplo:

```
<?php
    $dataNormal = $_POST['dataInicioCalendar']; // A DATA FORMATO BRAZIL
    $data = $_POST['dataInicio']; // A DATA AQUI É FORMATADA yyyy-MM-dd
```

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Documentação Oficial](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)</sub>

Comment: eu modifiquei o format no arquivo bootstrap-datepicker, vc acha que poderá atrapalhar?

Comment: @V.Avancini o que você alterou? dependendo sim!

Comment: var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
  autoclose: false,
  beforeShowDay: $.noop,
  calendarWeeks: false,
  clearBtn: true,
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
  endDate: Infinity,
  forceParse: true,
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  keyboardNavigation: true,
  language: 'pt',
  minViewMode: 0,
  multidate: false,
  multidateSeparator: '-',
  orientation: "auto",
  rtl: false,
  startDate: -Infinity,
  startView: 0,
  todayBtn: false,
  todayHighlight: false,
  weekStart: 0
 };

Já está como default no formato dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @V.Avancini eu acredito que não, se testou a minha solução.?

Comment: Não testei, pq tinha observado duas coisas, mudei como default a linguagem, eu mesmo tive que criar o padrão pt-BR e tbm mudei o formato, isso no dafault, como vc pôde ver ali no comentário acima

Comment: Ok, mas, o evento que eu estou chamando não está ali ... o resultado ta saindo num console, por enquanto mas, pode ser trabalhando de outra forma, em uma função por exemplo, primeiro teste depois tire as conclusões fico no aguardo. @V.Avancini

Comment: @V.Avancini no seu caso só precisa adicionar `.on('changeDate', function(e){
      console.log(e.date.toISOString())
      console.log(e.date.toISOString().substring(0,10));
  });` e o resultado que precisa dá uma olhada, as configurações padrões pelo visto não influencia em nada.

Comment: Mediante a muitos comentários eu entendi a sua duvida, e refiz algumas partes da minha resposta ... se quiser experimentar @V.Avancini

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#dateTo").datepicker({ 
    startDate: '01/01/1998', 
    endDate: '31/12/1998', 
    onSelect: checaVazio,
    onSelect:function(theDate) { 
        $("##dateTo").datepicker('option',{dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd') 

          } 
      }) 
})
```

faça isso para os dois codigos

Comment: deveria ter a vírgula ali depois do checaVazio?

Comment: sim tem q  ter, n havia visto

Comment: tente remover o checavazio, e colocar dentro do  function OnSelect

Comment: mas não posso remover o checaVazio, é um tratamento de erro